# System Configuration not defaulting to General

Tags: configuration, extensions, system.xml

When I click on System > Configuration it brings up the Catalin SEO configuration by default instead of the General tab.

I've edited the system.xml file for Catalin SEO to set the sort_order to be higher, but it just moves it further down the sidebar instead of stopping it from being loaded by default.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this happens when the sort_order is set "incorrectly" for a modules system config sections.

To update this simply find the `<sort_order>` for the section you are dealing with. It should look something like the following:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <your_section>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
```

You can either update this in the file directly, but this will be overridden on update. Or create your own module that depends on this module and simply add a config file with only this value being updated.

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <your_section>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order> <!-- add the new higher value here -->
        <your_section>
    <sections>
<config>
```

It is not a major problem so you could always just update the file.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the sort order should do the trick.
Just make sure you modify the right sort order.

Here is why modifying the `sort_order` of the section should work.

In `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Tabs::initTabs` there is this code:

```
$current = $this->getRequest()->getParam('section'); //this should be empty when accessing configuration through the menu.
```

Then there is this that retrieves all the sections:

```
$sections = $configFields->getSections($current);
```

Then the sections are sorted by `sort_order`

```
usort($sections, array($this, '_sort'));
```

And finally there is a loop through all the sections for some modifications and in this loop is checked if there is a section selected.
If there is no section selected, the first one that you have rights to, is set as the current section

```
        $sectionAllowed = $this->checkSectionPermissions($code);
        if ((empty($current) && $sectionAllowed)) {

            $current = $code;
            $this->getRequest()->setParam('section', $current);
        }
```

Make sure you edit the right `sort_order`. You shouldn't edit the sort order on the `tab` tag. Edit `<sort_order>` from inside the `<section>` tag.

As a side comment. This seams like a defect to me. The first default section should be the first section from the tab with the lowest sort order.

Comment: Isn't that a teensy bit big hammer for that? It's much easier to  change Catalin SEO extension section sort order to something a bit more appropriate (higher).

Comment: @Pronto. This is exactly what I was suggesting. Maybe I didn't express myself properly. I was trying to explain how and why changing the sort order for the section should work. and why changing the sort order for the tab does not work.

Comment: Mea culpa, now when you said it, it could be understood this way as well. I looked at first that you suggested to modify sorting algorithm itself.

Comment: @Pronto. I've re-read my answer and I guess you are right. It can be interpreted as modfying the sort algorithm. I added an extra line. Should be clear now...I hope.